# module.exports return value undefined

Tags: node.js, module, export, undefined

Little info, i have an arp.js file which takes a subnet address "192.168.2" and gets all strings returned from arp -a and stores in an array.

I can't figure out why my arpList function is returning an undefined value in my index.js file.

All the console.logs are returning the correct values in the arp.js page when called from the index.js, but the ipObj is coming up undefined. Even the console.log before i return of ipObj works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var { spawn } = require('child_process');
const arpLs = spawn('arp', ['-a']);
var bufferData;


module.exports = {
    arpList: function (subnet) {


        arpLs.stdout.on('data', data => {
            bufferData += data
        })


        arpLs.stderr.on('data', data => {
            console.log('error: ' + data);
        });


        arpLs.on('exit', function (code) {
            if (code != 0) {
                console.log("Error exiting"); //if error occurs
            }
            console.log("exit start 1"); // checking internal processes at stages
            var dataArray = bufferData.split(' ');
            var ipArray = [];
            for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                if (dataArray[i].includes(subnet)) {
                    ipArray.push(dataArray[i]);
                    console.log("loop working");
                }
            }
            var ipObj = { "lanIps": ipArray };
            console.log("Object is there: "+ipObj)
            return ipObj; // this obj should be returned to the index.js call using 
        })
    },
    sayMyName: function () {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

//arpList(ipSubnet);
//INDEX.js
//the index page looks like this
//var arp = require('./arp.js);
//var ipSubnet = "192.168.2";

//var lanIps = arp.arpList(ipSubnet);
//console.log(lanIps);
```

I ended up adding a callback function to arpList - function (subnet, callback)

Then instead of returning the value pass it into the callback

Then on the index.js side instead of

```
var lanIps = arp.arpList(value)
```

i used

```
arp.arpList(value, function(res){lanIps = res}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return ipObj; // this obj should be returned to the index.js call using
```

It won't be returned. [The reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) say nothing about return value. Node-style callbacks rarely work like that because they are potentially asynchronous and returned value cannot be taken into account.

This a special case of [this well-known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). The process is asynchronous and is finished after `arp.arpList(ipSubnet)` call, there's nothing to assign to `lanIps`. This is a use case for promises. There are already third-party promisified counterparts like [`child-process-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/child-process-promise).

The problem can be also solved by moving to synchronous API. `child_process` functions have synchronous counterparts, including [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options).

Comment: Ok so because it is async the index.js is grabbing the value before the value is available. This is why the console.log in the arp.js is coming back after the undefined value.

Comment: That's correct. I'd expect it to be solved nicely with child-process-promise and async/await, so it could be `var lanIps = await arp.arpList(ipSubnet)`.